# Linear approximation of membrane energy

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

From a reference I have in mesh processing the following well known equation is used to compute the area of a parametric surface

$$
A(\sigma) = E_M(\sigma) = \int_U \sqrt{EF - G^2}dU
$$

Which is also called membrane energy, $E,F$ and $G$ are the coefficients of the first fundamental form. However minimizing such form, even numerically, is difficult, therefore usually the following linearization is proposed

$$
\tilde{E}_M(\sigma) = \int_U \lVert \sigma_u \rVert^2 + \lVert \sigma_v\rVert^2 dU
$$

However I do struggle to understand why this linearization is true, can anyone suggest how to get the second integral from the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no idea what people do in numerics to find minimal surfaces, however, I can give an answer to the analytical side of your question.

There have been quite a few different methods for solving the Plateau problem. 
In general, we have the inequality
$$\begin{align*}\|\sigma_u\wedge \sigma_v\|
=\sqrt{\|\sigma_u\|^2\|\sigma_v\|^2-\langle\sigma_u,\sigma_v\rangle^2}
&=\sqrt{EF-G^2} \\
&\leq \frac12(\|\sigma_u\|^2+\|\sigma_v\|^2)
=\frac12\|(\sigma_u,\sigma_v)\|^2
=\frac12\|\nabla\sigma\|^2
\end{align*}
$$
with equality if and only if $\|\sigma_u\|=\|\sigma_v\|$ and $\langle\sigma_u,\sigma_v\rangle=0$. 
(You can see this by squaring and rearranging the inequality, to get the equivalent inequality which trivially holds true,
$$
0
\leq
\langle\sigma_u,\sigma_v\rangle^2 + (\|\sigma_u\|^2 - \|\sigma_v\|^2)^2
$$
with equality as above.)

A parametric surface $\sigma\colon B\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^n$ which fulfils the two conditions above is called *conformally parametrised*.
Thus, in general, the area functional $A(\sigma)=\int_B \|\sigma_u\wedge \sigma_v\| dudv$ is dominated by the so-called *Dirichlet energy* $D(\sigma)=\frac12 \int_B \|\nabla\sigma\|^2dudv$ with equality if and only if $\sigma$ is conformally parametrised.

Classically, you would first try to minimise the Dirichlet energy because the energy integrand has better regularity properties. For instance, it is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$ and $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}\setminus\{0\}$. Another important feature of $D$ is the invariance under *conformal* reparametrisations of the domain $B$.
This contrasts the area functional, whose integrand is only $C^1$ on the smaller set of rank-2 matrices but which is invariant under the larger class of diffeomorphic reparametrisations (which is a bad thing).

You can use a compactness argument to find a minimiser $\sigma$ of $D$. Subsequently, when you do an *inner* variation of the energy functional you realise that vanishing inner variation (due to the minimality) of the energy already means that the surface $\sigma$ is conformally parametrised!
Hence, you know that area functional and the Dirichlet energy of $\sigma$ yield the same value and so you have found a surface of minimal energy which also is an area minimiser.

For instance, this is how they do it in Chapter 4 of the book [Minimal surfaces I](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783662027912) by Dierkes, Hildebrandt, Küster and Wohlrab.

Comment: [This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2585097) is a paper by Dziuk and Hutchinson that exploits this numerically in the case of topological disks and [this](http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=1463-9963&vol=6&iss=2&rank=4&srch=searchterm%7Cl) does the same for topological cylinders.

Comment: @Sven Pistre, great answer. How did you bound $\sqrt{EF-G^2}$ with the average of the norms?

Comment: @user8469759, there was a typo in the inequality. I've fixed it and updated my answer.

Comment: Do you mind working out all the math? I'm not sure what typo are you talking about, I can still see the inequality $$\sqrt{EF-G^2}
 \leq \frac12(\|\sigma_u\|^2+\|\sigma_v\|^2)$$, this is bit I'm missing.

Comment: The squares under the square root were missing on the left hand side of: $$\sqrt{\|\sigma_u\|^2\|\sigma_v\|^2-\langle\sigma_u,\sigma_v\rangle^2}
\leq \frac12(\|\sigma_u\|^2+\|\sigma_v\|^2)
$$. The terms under the square root are exactly the coefficients $$E,F,G$$ of the first fundamental form. I have updated the answer above with another line which might help you realise why the inequality is true (transform to an equivalent inequality which trivially holds true and incorporates the conformality conditions.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a ‘true’ linearization. Moreover, one can show (from the dimension analysis) that you can scale one of the parameters $u$ or $v$ to make $\tilde E_M$ as bad as you want.

However, if we believe that our maps are square enough (i.e. $\lVert\sigma_u\rVert\approx\lVert\sigma_v\rVert$ and $(\sigma_u,\sigma_v)\approx0$), then:

$$
\sqrt{EG-F^2} \approx \lVert\sigma_u\rVert\cdot\lVert\sigma_v\rVert\approx\frac12\left(\lVert\sigma_u\rVert^2 + \lVert\sigma_v\rVert^2\right)
$$

Comment: About the *square enough* I'm with you, but this isn't a linearization then what is it?

Comment: It is an “approximation”.

Comment: Is this kind of approximation used elsewhere, apart from my application?

Comment: Nothing I am aware of. In scientific applications, it's not a big deal to minimize the initial integral. If you want efficiency in real-time and you don't worry a lot about precision, 2nd integral is ok. Finally, you can estimate the error $E_M-\tilde E_M$ and check whether the solution is good enough for you.

Comment: By the way... the word `linearization` wasn't mine.